# How to deal with a multi-brand Vue.js project that loads different types of components?

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a multi-brand Vue.js project.

Based on domain we will determine the brand. All brands will use the same routes, but load different components in the views. Views can also share some components.

For example;

Brand #1 Uses component 1, 2, 3

Brand #2 Uses component 3, 5, 6

What would be the best structure for that case?

1) Solve in routes file. We will load a view based on the brand code. For example: views/brand1/home.vue and views/brand2/home.vue

2) Solve in view file. Based on the brand parameter load specific components.

3) Other...

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

i voted to close your question because it's primarily opionion based and depends very much on the specific implementation details of your application.

in terms of code-splitting and reusability, it could be possible to map your usecase into the pattern of lazy routes https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#lazy-loading-routes